# Place image position on top of button programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview, position

I have a button on tap of which I need to show an image view which I did like below in button action

```
    let imageName = "pointed_image.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    self.addSubview(imageView)
```

Now i want to position that image on top of button such that bottom center of image lies exactly on top center of button. (Imagine a callout view how it displays in map where pin is the location(button in my scenario) and callout alert is the "starbucks callout" of location (image in my scenario) -  [image: like this]

Pls advice how shall i modify the below code to meet the requirement

```
    //Build image view
    let imageName = "pointed_image.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

    //Get Button frame
    let btnFrame = self.infoButton.frame

    //position image on top of buttom
    // CODE TO MODIFY BELOW
    var imgFrame: CGRect = imageView.frame
    imgFrame.origin.x = btnFrame.origin.x + 10
    imgFrame.origin.y = btnFrame.origin.y - 10
    imageView.frame = imgFrame
    self.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: I would recommend using autolayout.. are you calculating frames in the rest of the app as well?

Comment: I need this image view to be renderend at different places in my code. So I want to do this programatically where the image positions on top of button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `imageView`'s `center` property to place it correctly:

```
                           // aligned by centers in x axis
imageView.center = CGPoint(x: self.infoButton.center.x, 
                           // in y axis, using buttons origin and imageView's height placed right on top of the button
                           y: self.infoButton.frame.origin.y - (imageView.bounds.height / 2))
```

Comment: Hi Milan: this worked but my imageView is placed behind other views. I tried to bring this to front but none of them are working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ashh well that depends on where do you put that `imageView` and what is your view hierarchy.. and I don't know anything about either of those

Comment: @Ashh you missed that again :)